# NSFormatter used with a NSPopUpButton

Tags: cocoa, formatting, interface-builder, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

I have a NSPopUpButton whose content values are bound to an NSArray of NSNumbers. The NSPopUpButton correctly displays the array of numbers in it's popup-menu. However, when I change the selected value, I receive a message:

```
HIToolbox: ignoring exception 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "tempo"; desired type = NSNumber; given type = NSCFString; value = 106.' that raised inside Carbon event dispatch
```

Obviously, this is occurring because the object to which the selected value is bound to is expecting an NSNumber, and the NSPopUpButton is giving it an NSString. Looking through other posts, I think what I need is a NSNumberFormatter.

However, I have tried using an NSNumberFormatter, both through Interface Builder, and programatically, but the result does not change. For reference, this is the code which I have used when attempting to set the formatter of the NSPopUpButton programatically:

```
tempoFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[tempoFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[tempoFormatter setFormat:@"### bpm"];

[[tempoButton cell] setFormatter:tempoFormatter];
```

(tempoButton is an IBOutlet connected to the NSPopUpButton)

I am wondering if using an NSNumberFormatter is even what I need? If so, what I am doing wrong? I have read through the Data Formatting Programming Guide; it seems very straight-forward, but I feel like I am missing something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you getting the selected object? Are you binding to `selectedObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on which binding you're using to get NSPopupButton's selected value.

If you're binding to "Selected Value", you'll get a NSString.

If you're binding to "Selected Object", you'll get the object represented by the selection, which in your case would be an NSNumber.

Otherwise, you would add a NSValueTransformer to your binding to transform the selected value into the object you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks Darren, your comments pointed me in the right direction. I didn't notice the difference between Selected/Content Values and Objects. After making sure I used the Objects instead of Values, I do not receive the error message any more, and the edited value is successfully stored. However, I do want to format the NSNumber value into the format "### bpm" when it is displayed in the popup-menu. I'm still having difficulties getting this to work; NSNumbers are being displayed as just that.

Comment: CJ: You should ask a separate question about that.